# How to resolve fast ai module not found error

Tags: python, module, fast-ai

I am working through the Fast AI material and when I run the following Python code:

```
!pip install -Uqq fastbook
import fastbook
fastbook.setup_book()
```

I get this error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.vision.all'
```

I have tried to update the installation using `conda install fastbook -c fasti` and also tried restarting the runtime, however it still isn't working. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install -U 'fastai>=2.0.0'`?

Comment: Thanks, I get a large error message. Looks like I need to update torch ?#
The conflict is caused by:
    fastai 2.1.8 depends on torch>=1.7.0